# Is it possible to re-transmit a packet after capturing it using XDP and processing it in userspace?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, packet-capture, packet-injection

I need to write an application that sits between two servers and modifies HTTP packets sent from one server to another by adding a specific HTTP header to each packet.
Apparently it has to be done as fast as possible, I have found that by using eBFP and XDP, I can capture packets with high performance, but as far as I can see XDP verdicts are either *abort, drop, pass, and tx*.
Using *tx* verdict I can send the captured packet to a user space program to modify it, but I couldn't figure out how to send the packet after header modification? This video [here](https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/ebpf_xdp/) is an explanation of what can be done using eBPF and XDP, and it states that it can be done, but I couldn't find out how.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find out something? I may have several inputs.

Comment: @Aif No, I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `XDP_TX` will *not* let the packet through user-space. It will return the packet on the same NIC it comes from. Also, you can modify the packet, but I don't see easy way to expand the packet. Hence, to write additional header, you would have to override some datas.

It looks like you have two options:

- Rely on a L7 HTTP reverse proxy (to add the header)
- Use an nfqueue if you want to prevent packets from reaching your host and send them back.

Comment: "It will return the packet on the same NIC it comes from." Can you send to any NIC now according to this: https://lwn.net/Articles/887184/

Answer (score 0):

If you still interested in the topic, the answer is no. However, XDP socket can be use to forward/send new packet from kernel space or user space. Checkout XDP tutorial on github, or look at code in the Linux kernel `samples/bpf`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the XDP tutorial (as a convenience)?

Comment: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial
Best source, but also you can take a look at samples in kernel tree.